# How to install OpenCV Manager on a emulator?

Tags: android, opencv

Running the OpenCV for Android samples on the emulator requires installation of OpenCV Manager. I have x86 architecture on my device. Many tutorials simply say install OpenCV Manager. Can you please tell me how exactly to do this?

I tried using "adb install" to install it but it didn't work. I was in the correct directory and adb otherwise works fine. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

OpenCV Manager apk file is included into the OpenCV SDK.

You can install it running:

```
adb install <...>/OpenCV-2.4.3.2-android-sdk/apk/OpenCV_2.4.3.2_Manager_2.4_x86.apk
```

(For other SDK releases path will be slightly different but similar)

Comment: Yoda: Put this in the command line -- such as Powershell or cmd.exe.  adb is located in your Android SDK directory -- for me, it is located in:
C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Comment: Its giving me a error. "Invalid apk file". any Idea? I used "./adb install /Android/OpenCV4android/apk/OpenCV_2.4.9_Manager_2.18_armeabi.apk"